# How to change device ringtone to NONE in android programmatically

Tags: android

I want to change the device ringtone to none (No ringtone) on the app install. I have tried with the audio manager but it's not working with some of the devices.

> I want to select ringtone type like below Images

[image]

> I have found this code but it will show the list of default ringtone I don't want like that I want to set directly to none as a default selected

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RingtoneManager.ACTION_RINGTONE_PICKER);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_TYPE,
RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION|RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_SHOW_DEFAULT, true);
intent.putExtra(RingtoneManager.EXTRA_RINGTONE_DEFAULT_URI,
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION));
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

> Worked to select None mode

```
   RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this,RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE,null);
```

> Not Working for silent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get the perfect answer but following answer may help you please check

> Select ringtone mode NONE

```
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, null);
```

> Select ringtone mode SILENCE but on some devices it causing silent music volume and ringer silent

```
AudioManager ringerMode = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
ringerMode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

> Temporarily I have handled like below where I am causing issue

```
if (Build.BRAND.equalsIgnoreCase("xiaomi") || 
Build.MANUFACTURER.equalsIgnoreCase("vivo")) {
RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(this, 
RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, null);
} else {
    ringerMode.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
}
```